# No provider for HttpResponse - angular5 StaticInjectorError (AppModule)[AppComponent -> HttpResponse]

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpresponse, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to do something I think is pretty basic.
moving ahead from a simple login.html page, the server adds a header to the response to specify who logged in - admin/company/customer.

```
response.setHeader("user", "admin");
```

All I'm trying to achieve in Angular is access to this response header - to determine which component I need to show -admin/company/customer.

for that I plan to use the 'HttpResponse' *thingy* and get access to the header in the app.component constructor, like so:

```
constructor(private myResponse: HttpResponse<any>) {

var user = myResponse.headers.get("user");
```

I've imported HttpResponse on the top of app.component.ts page
I've imported it also in the top of app.module.ts, but I can't seem to add it to the 'imports' or 'providers' array's listed below.

'HttpClientModule' is present there, however, moving forward from the login page and into the 'index.html'- I'm getting an error:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: 
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> HttpResponse]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> HttpResponse]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpResponse!
at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
at resolveDep (core.js:12619)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**
screenshots:
[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B9Rf.png)
[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6cSx.png)

Comment: HttpResponse should not be imported as a service. Could you please post the code where you are requesting the login?

Comment: the login page is outside of the angular framework. is just a plain standard login page with name, password and 'client type' select box. it then sends that information to a dedicated servlet that determines if this login is valid. if it is - then a session is created, a header with the 'client type' is added to the response, and then redirects to index.html

Comment: In that case, you don't really have access to the response after the re-direct.
You should be sending the login request from the Angular Application. 

If you just want to pass the username to the angular app, you can simply send it in as a query param on the re-direct.